# Use Objective-C in Swift as a Library

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, opentok

I have a Swift project that uses a library called OpenTok. I need to use an Objective-C class that has the same dependency(OpenTok) in my Swift project. The problem is when I use the objective C file it imports all the unnecessary libraries into Swift Project.

**My question** is how I can use Objective C files in my project as libraries that point to the same dependencies as the app, so once the app imports my Objective-C libraries, there will be no conflicts such as `"One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined."` error.

Comment: To clarify, you have a Swift target with OpenTok as a dependency and an Objective-C target as a dependency. Then the Objective-C target in turn has an OpenTok dependancy?

Comment: Exactly! I need to use some Objective Files as a dependency in my Swift Target while OpenTok should be used both in swift target and objective-C as dependency

Comment: Do you have 1 target or two? Using Objective-C files in a Swift target shouldn't affect the dependency tree. Can you share how you are importing OpenTok in Objective-C?

Comment: I have one target which is the main app. My question is how I can  add Obj-c files as a library into the swift project. I want to separate Obj-c files from the main app.

Comment: You should use `SPM` it will manage dependencies for you.

Comment: You need to create a new library/package/target (depending on how you want to manage this) in the xcode menus, and in there put your objc code. then you can import it into your swift target. 

If you go down this route, you will then have to worry about making sure the OpenTok SDK is available in your objc target and your swift target. You can add objc files to a swift project without making a new library/package/target, you can just create > new then xcode will ask you to add a briding header.

Comment: @Cy-4AH OpenTok does not support SPM unfortunately…

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a framework for your Objective-C files and Embed to your main project.
2. The new objc framework should link the OpenTok as well.
3. Insure the mach-type of objc framework and OpenTok is "Static Library".

If you import OpenTok as Dynamic Library, with this kind of dependency relationship, there will be two copies of OpenTok symbols in your app binary.
So the "One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined." warning will appear when starting the App.